# Windows Store: Easy image fade-in

Tags: windows-store-apps

Windows Store XAML apps have access to a [slew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh452703.aspx) of transitions and theme animations to remove tons and tons of ball-aching with animations, triggers, custom controls etc. to make an app move nicely.

That said, does anyone know how to use these stock items to make an image fade-in on load?

I've tried randomly stuffing all kinds of XxxThemeTransition and XxxThemeAnimation to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/). There is an extension to `Image` of `FadeInOnLoad`. About as easy as it can get. Reference the namespace; attach the property.

Comment: Cheers Nate, I went ahead and wrote an attached property but due to a issue/bug within the framework I've not fully tested it, but I'll post it here when I'm happy with it.